# Failed to open files as files damaged when download from PHP

Tags: php, download, php-7, php-7.3

I am using `PHP 7.3.22` in my Mac machine and I am trying to download files using PHP function. But I am unable to open the downloaded files as they are damaged. I am using the below code to download

```
function downloadFile()
{
    $fileName = 'MyFile.zip';
    $fullPath = '/path/to/MyFile.zip';
    if(file_exists($fullPath)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        $contentType = mime_content_type($fullPath);
        header('Pragma: public');  // required
        header('Expires: 0');  // no cache
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Content-Type: '.$contentType);
        header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($fullPath)) . ' GMT');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:  binary");
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullPath)); // provide file size
        header('Connection: close');
        readfile($fullPath);
        exit();
    }
}
```

**The download is not restricted for single file type. So getting the content type programatically**

While opening the zip file after download, it is showing "Unadle to expand'MyFile.zip'. It is an unsupported format"

Am I doing something wrong here? Please help me to make this work. Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code can be simplified:

```
$file_name = '/path/to/MyFile.zip';
if(file_exists($file_name)) {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
    readfile($file_name);
    exit;
}
```

You have to make sure if the PHP can read the source file; recommended to use a relative path instead of an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo. Fixed that. Even with the correct content type, there is the same result

Comment: Got it. Lots of header entries can be omitted. See if the revised codes work for you.